# equals() method and '==' operator for primitive data types and class data types

Tags: java, class, object, methods, operators

I already know that `equals()` method (or any other one similar to this) compares values of a given type between objects and the `==` operator compares if both references declared in the expression are the same, but I have a question when comparing every field of two objects from the same class, the code is like:

```
//fields are String name, String surname, int age and boolean gender belonging to the Person class.
public boolean isYou(Person person)
{
    return 
    getName().compareToIgnoreCase(person.getName()) == 0 &&
    getSurname().compareToIgnoreCase(person.getSurname()) == 0 &&
    getAge() == person.getAge() &&
    getGender() == person.getGender();
```

Having this implementation taken into account, is it correct to state that is mandatory to use the methods to compare class data types (like String) and that is possible to use the `==` operator when dealing with primitive data types even though an object comparison is done instead of a simple comparison like `getAge() == 2`?

Comment: `person.getAge()` isn't an object--its type is `int`, which makes it a primitive. Operators are applied to an expression's type, not based on whatever components make up an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it correct to state that is mandatory to use the methods to compare class data types (like String)

Yes.

> and that is possible to use the == operator when dealing with primitive data types

Yes.

> even though an object comparison is done instead of a simple comparison like getAge() == 2?

No. It is not correct to say this. Primitive types are not objects, so there is no `equals()` method to call, so your only choice is to compare values via `==`, and in the case of primitive types that always yields the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

That’s absolutely correct, dealing with primitive type such as int double byte char, and so on, you must compare them using ==, MUST because they are not objects so they don’t implements equals(). So clarified that, the rest is ok